# Database access and storing of models in memory

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I'm creating a javafx application but i got a question about the way dealing with my database. The datas contains in my database are getting with the DAOs object that i create. After they are added in their respective Model objects, ObservableList etc ... Some data contained in my models are rarely updated but others are updated very often. When i say updated i'm talking about updates on Models not database.

So I don't know what's the best solutions between these two:

1. I load all the app's Models needed at on start, save them somewhere (class with static field ?). And when one these value are updated i directly save the modification in the database.
2. I load all the app's Models needed at on start, save them somewhere (class with static field ?). But only save the modification when the users leave the app. It showing a loading screen, and the app save all the modifications in the database.

I would lean towards the second one because the first one poses performance problems because of the numerous sql requests.

If i had to create a java class with all my models, i will do a class like this:

```
public static ObservableValue<Boolean> value1;

public static ObservableValue<String> value2;

public static ObservableValue<Boolean> value3;

public static ObservableList value4;

etc ...
```

In fact i don't know how to store my Models in the app, and get them when i had to.

Should i use Dependency injection to inject my DAOs in the views that need them ? injecting with guice.

Thanks you very much.

EDIT:
My dao system is like this:
I have an abstract class called DAO:

```
public abstract class DAO<T> {

    protected Connection connection = null;

    public DAO(Connection connection){
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public abstract Service<Boolean> create(T obj);

    public abstract Service<Boolean> delete(List<Integer> obj);

    public abstract Service<Boolean> modify(ObservableList<T> obj);

    public abstract Service<T> find(int id);

    public abstract Service<ObservableList<T>> getAll();

}
```

and some child extending this class.
And a factory class that created DAO object for me:

```
/**
 * Factory générant des object {Dao<T>} permetant d'intéragir avec la BDD
 */
public class DAOFactory {

    private static final Connection conn = new TradingDatabase().getInstance();

    /**
     * Retourne un objet DAO<Risk> intéragissant avec la BDD
     * @return DAO
     */
    public static DAO<Risk> getRiskDAO(){
        return new RiskDAO(conn);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Guice is a good option, normally the layer is using DAOs must be a service or a business layer that needs data to make logic.

I would suggest you also take a look at how [Redis](https://redis.io/) works, it is super useful.

Comment: I edited my question to add some informations. You respond to my last question but i don't know if "redis" responding to the first.

Comment: for the first question: in my opinion is better to keep it simple and save the data right away, saving the data somewhere to be sent to the database will just add more complexity and you also need to think of the situations that the data might become stale.

Redis is a good option when your data is not getting updated very often and you don't want to query it often from the database, so you can keep using the cache data.